# remote Head->master is two commits past origin/master, I want them to be the same

Tags: git

Somehow master got separated from  origin/master.
I made two commits and pushed them, but now my  HEAD->master is not the
same as  origin/master.  How do I move origin/master to Head->master,
since that is the last and most recent commit.

I can't seem to add text to show what git displays, it thinks it is code

Thank you

Comment: can you add the image what git displays?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+repository